# How to run Visual Studio 2008 projects in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

How do I run Visual Studio 2008 projects in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: What is Visual Studio 2009, by the way?

Comment: the IDE in for creating .Net Applications

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/11/20/vs2005-and-vs2008-co-existence.aspx) by Jon Skeet about moving solutions and projects between VS2005 and VS2008.

Jon's conclusions:

- It's possible to share project files but not solution files between VS2005 and VS2008.
- If you upgrade a solution file by mistake, it's very easy to fix it by hand.
- If you decide to maintain different solution files, if there are big changes in one it may be easiest to just make them in one solution, then upgrade again.
- Creating a project in VS2005 and then importing it into VS2008 is seamless; the other way round has slight issues which are fixable by hand.
- I don't know of a way of forcing VS2008 to only use C# 2 while at the same time maintaining VS2005 compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you picked 2009.  A terrible year.  2007 we might have guessed 2008, but 2009 is smack dab in the middle.

I'm not sure what the answer will be, but I'd guess that your best approach is to just add each code file and each reference until the project works.

I don't know what the file formats look like, but there usually isn't going to be support in an older version for a newer version's format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that VS2005 has forward compatibility... haven't heard of that many apps that do.